# Laravel reset password link for each users type

Tags: php, laravel, reset-password

I want to send reset link to user email address, I have tree type of users and tree tables for each of them. 
Also I create tree guard that I seperate them by this guards.
I can send reset email for each of them, but the route for each one is not same and have just a prefix for each users.
for example for student the reset link shoule be this :

```
http://localhost:8000/student/password/reset/e39f6ef2a2cc4d88c1b7be6afc9ecfe876f9dc194b98740347e8c842aa17554b
```

and for admin this:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/password/reset/e39f6ef2a2cc4d88c1b7be6afc9ecfe876f9dc194b98740347e8c842aa17554b
```

How I can send email by correct link?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do like this.

1. At first use one common form to select user type.
2. Then use 3 different type of forms for 3 different types of users to
   give their email or whatever information to reset password. Only 1
   particular user form will show up based on selected user type from
   first form. You can use jquery/JavaScript to show up the second
   form. Then from the second form action, you can call 3 different type
   of routes.